# Mongoose - How to exclude _id from the result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am getting an issue getting the desired output like this

```
[
   {
       "status": "ONBOARD"
       "count": 1
   },
   {
       "status": "PENDING"
       "count": 1
   },
]
```

I am getting like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "status": "ONBOARD"
        },
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "status": "CLIENT_ROUND"
        },
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "status": "SCREENED"
        },
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

Here is my aggregate :

```
const result = await Lead.aggregate([

      {
        $group: {
          _id: { status: '$status' },
          count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
        $project: { _id: 0, status: 1, count: 1 }
      }
```

Help me to get the output I am new I have applied `$project` but giving me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. With `status: "$_id.status"` in the projection stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        status: "$status"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      status: "$_id.status",
      count: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U3GbNcHqH2t)

---

Or just `$group` with `_id: "$status"`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$status",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      status: "$_id",
      count: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gcx8xGDbVDy)